# Get decorated function from within nested decorator

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I'm trying to get the reference to the originally decorated function from within a decorator. How can this be done?

```
import inspect
from functools import wraps


def test_decorator(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # the closest I could get to getting the original function:
        # it prints the frame from which the function was called.
        current_frame = inspect.currentframe()
        outer_frames = inspect.getouterframes(current_frame)
        print(outer_frames[-1].frame)
        
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


@test_decorator
@test_decorator
@test_decorator
def test_func(a, b, c):
    print("func")


test_func(1,2,3)
```

The 'originally decorated function' in this context would be `test_func`, since it's the target function we're decorating. I've looked through the `inspect` module, the closest I could get is by getting the first frame on the stack, but it doesn't help much.

Maybe, there is a solution already in stdlib?

Comment: Isn't it simply `func` in your case? Try adding `print("It's me:", func)` under `def wrapper(...):`

Comment: @Rafael-WO no, it's not, unfortunately. Decorators stack, but on top of each other. Obviously, the only one seeing the real `func` is the last `@test_decorator`.

Comment: @Rafael-WO this is the problem I'm trying to solve, actually. To see the original function from any decorator in the stack.

Comment: What about using the `__wrapped__` attribute? if you design all your decorators carefully, you could find the original functions down the rabbit hole of all the nested `__wrapped__` attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

https://github.com/micheles/decorator

```
import inspect
from decorator import decorator


@decorator
def test_decorator(func, *args, **kwargs):
    print(inspect.getfullargspec(func))
    return func(*args, **kwargs)


@test_decorator
@test_decorator
@test_decorator
def test_func(a, b, c):
    print("func")


test_func(1,2,3)
```

Now from within each `test_decorator` it prints:

```
FullArgSpec(args=['a', 'b', 'c'], varargs=None, varkw=None, defaults=None, kwonlyargs=[], kwonlydefaults=None, annotations={})
```

Bless this man who wrote the module, the guy is a legend.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [@Jorge E. Cardona](https://stackoverflow.com/users/361023/jorge-e-cardona) comment I ended up doing the following:

```
from functools import wraps
import inspect

def decorator(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        
        wraped_func = func
        
        while hasattr(wraped_func, "__wrapped__"):
            wraped_func = wraped_func.__wrapped__
        print(inspect.getfullargspec(wraped_func))
        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper

@decorator
@decorator
@decorator
def decorated_func(arg1, arg2):
    ...
```

Now if you call, the `decorated_func`:

```
decorated_func(1, 2)
```

The output will be:

```
FullArgSpec(args=['arg1', 'arg2'], varargs=None, varkw=None, defaults=None, kwonlyargs=[], kwonlydefaults=None, annotations={})
FullArgSpec(args=['arg1', 'arg2'], varargs=None, varkw=None, defaults=None, kwonlyargs=[], kwonlydefaults=None, annotations={})
FullArgSpec(args=['arg1', 'arg2'], varargs=None, varkw=None, defaults=None, kwonlyargs=[], kwonlydefaults=None, annotations={})
```

A print for each decorator being called.

Comment: By any chance do you know how to get the full arg specs being exposed by an inner function from within the decorator?

Comment: @AndreaMoro can you provide an example? I am not sure I understand what you need